# Why are the search center settings incorrect after I change them in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, search, search-center

I am running the PowerShell script below to change the search center url on my site collection. After I run the script, I go to the UI and see that the checkbox is enabled to inherit the search center settings. But in my script I set this checkbox on false.

```
        $site = Get-SPSite https://myCompany.com
        $web = Get-SPWeb $site.Url        
        $web.AllProperties["SRCH_SB_SET_SITE"] = '{"Inherit":false,"ResultsPageAddress":"{SearchCenterURL}/SearchResultsAll.aspx,"ShowNavigation":false}'
        $web.AllProperties["SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL_SITE"] = '/Paginas'
        $web.Update();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Central Admin displays Farm-level settings, but you're changing the settings for a specific SPWeb. If you'll take a look at https://spsamer.com/2013/07/22/sharepoint-2013-csom-property-bag-properties/, you can see all the different properties that can be set, including three different options for the Search Center URL:

**Search Center URL**

KEY: SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL

TYPE: string:RelPath

VALUE EXAMPLE: /sites/xyz/SearchCenter/Pages

**Search Center URL (SITE)**

KEY: SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL_SITE

TYPE: string:RelPath

VALUE EXAMPLE: /sites/xyz/SearchCenter/Pages

**Search Center URL (Web)**

KEY: SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL_WEB

TYPE: string:RelPath

VALUE EXAMPLE: /sites/xyz/SearchCenter/Pages

Still, you won't be able to update the Central Admin settings by changing a property on a single SPWeb, and I'm not sure exactly where the global property (SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL) would need to be set. Possibly on the Central Admin RootWeb?

Comment: But in the ui it is possible to configure this on sitecollection level. I expect that it is also possible in powershell.